# notepad++ removing first word in every line

Tags: regex, numbers, notepad++

i am looking for a way to delete the first word in every line in notepad++.

The list looks like this:

```
jon52_rs - £5
caneflagi - £5
Tehhguam - £5
Clapu - £5-05
```

and i want this:

```
- £5
- £5
- £5
- £5.05
```

or ideally only the numbers (5,5,5,5.05). I tried this with one method, however it deleted all the comma numbers like 5.05.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to convert `-` in `.` as for `5-05`

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use..

```
Find: ^\S+[ ]
Replace:
```

Answer (score 4):

In Notepad++

Find: `^\w+\s+(.*)` 
Replace: `\1`

`^` beginning of the line
`\w` word
`\s` space
`(.*)` argument - following any number of characters

`\1` Keep the first argument

Answer (score 1):

> I am looking for a way to delete the first word in every line in notepad++.

It should work.

```
^(\w+)(.*)
```

[demo](http://regex101.com/r/rI6yA4/4)

---

> ideally only the numbers

try this one if you need only numbers:

```
^(.*)£(.*)
```

[demo](http://regex101.com/r/rI6yA4/3)

---

In Notepad++

Find what : `^(\w+)(.*)`

Replace with `$2` or `\2`